# SQLite select order by alphabet first, then all other characters

Tags: sqlite

I have a SQLite db with a table, containing rows with different names. For example:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | antony |
| 2 | % |
| 3 | 10 |
| 4 | stackoverflow |
| 5 | john |

I get the data from this table with

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 1 ORDER BY name Asc LIMIT ?, ?
```

And it returns

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | % |
| 3 | 10 |
| 1 | antony |
| 5 | john |
| 4 | stackoverflow |

But i want it to return names in alphabetical order first, then all other names which starts with non letters in the right order too. So i want to get:

| id | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | antony |
| 5 | john |
| 4 | stackoverflow |
| 2 | % |
| 3 | 10 |

How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the operator [`GLOB`](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#the_like_glob_regexp_and_match_operators) to check if the name starts with a letter in the `ORDER BY` clause:

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*' DESC, name
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=83286ce3aa355b49ca560da4618d5c9f).

Comment: Great, Thanks! But actually, i forgot to point one thing in the question, i also have cyrillic words in the table, so i want this order: cyrillic words -> english words -> rest of the rows
How can I achieve that?
If i use ORDER BY name GLOB '[А-Яа-яA-Za-z]*' DESC, name it returns cyrillic words after english words

Comment: @MickeyMouse Then you need 3 expressions in the ORDER BY clause: `ORDER BY name GLOB '[?]*' DESC, name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*' DESC, name`. Replace the `?` with the cyrillic letters respective to the english `A-Za-z`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @forpas, just wish to add

If you wish to make Case insensitive sorting, you may try as below

```
SELECT * 
FROM tablename 
ORDER BY name GLOB '[A-Za-z]*' DESC, Upper(name)
```